# SQL Server 2008 R2 intermittent connectivity issue

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, database-connection

I have a VB application which is connecting to a SQL Server 2008 R2 database. Recently, there is an intermittent issue with connectivity.

When I log in to application, at first there is no issue and I am able to process the data successfully. However after some time (around 10-15mins) it shows the error "ODBC -- Call failed" in Application and auto-closed. 
When I re-login to application the error shown below appears.

However if I restart the PC issue is resolved but the same cycle repeats - works for a few data and then displays the error.

Database connection error during application log in:

[image: Database connection error during application log in]

Assume this issue may be related to database connection or database corruption. Could any one please assist here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isue is related to creating an SSL client credential. Flipping
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.0\Client\ Enabled` from 0 to 1 may fix your problem

Comment: Hi Tony,                                                                                            Thanks for the response. I can only see "Protocols -> SSL 2.0", using Win7 OS

Comment: Moreover at the below path  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.0\Client I have two options "Default" and "DisabledByDefault" no "Enabled" option.

Comment: Hi All Could anyone please help here ?

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/3de77e02-8e5b-474a-a92d-385dd43d52f1/sql-server-error?forum=sqldataaccess

Comment: It was mentioned as "thanks for the reply.... we resolved the issue it was a crzay VIRUS problem.... thanks" however the root cause or solution is not mentioned. Can re-install of SQL Server will work ?

Comment: Hi All, we put some code for capturing more information regarding the error and found the issue is with "[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Communication link failure". Could anyone please help on this issue ?